# Rails logger formatting - insert method name calling logger method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to insert name of the method calling the logger methods into my log files.  Not the whole stack trace, but the class, method and/or line number would be great.

In any method, one can use `caller` to get an array of strings, each of which contains the file, line number and method name.  I've come up with a pretty awful kludge using regexes and `Enumerable#find` to try to return the first non-logger stack frame.  I guess it works, but if the locations of the logging Ruby files change in a different version or Rails, or I name my files something to do with logs, it will break.  Same with if I take a given index from the top of the stack (I did this at first, then refactored one thing and naturally it gave me the wrong frame).

Note that I'm not looking to just log the controller or action, as those can be retrieved easily.  Mostly this is for stuff in the `lib/` directory.

Isn't there an easy way to do this?  I don't want to have to pass in `__method__` every time I make a logging statement.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked all over at different solutions for capturing the exact place (file, line number, method name) where I invoke any given logger instance method from within my rails app.  To do this, you need to override Logger's format_message method, and a good place to do this is in your rails project's `config/environment.rb` file.

This is what I've come up with, which is good enough for me ;o)

```
class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    line = ''
    Kernel.caller.each{|entry|
      if (entry.include? Rails.root.to_s)
        line = " #{entry.gsub(Rails.root.to_s,'').gsub(/\/(.+)\:in `(.+)'/, "\\1 -> \\2")}"
        break
      end
    }
    "[#{timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d.%H:%M:%S")}] #{severity}#{line}: #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

`Kernel.caller` holds an enumerable array of the entire backtrace.  If you look at it in its entirety, you'll see most calls are internal inside of a gem somewhere well outside your project.  I've found that by looping through the `Kernel.caller` until I find the first place that includes my `Rails.root`, I can get the line with the information I want to parse.

Example:
If I call `Rails.logger.debug("Streamer class started!")` from the start method of my Streamer class, the raw entry would look like this:

```
/Users/chikoon/www/my_rails_app/lib/streamer.rb:7:in `start'
```

so by the time it makes it through my formatter, I've got the timestamp, severity mode, the file path, line number, method name, and message:

```
[20140919.19:23:44] DEBUG lib/streamer.rb:7 -> start: Streamer class started!
```

I hope that helps get your wheels turning.

Comment: I wish I could give this answer 100 upvotes instead of 1—this is the only answer that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up log_tags to call the `__method__`?

```
Blog::Application.configure do
  config.log_tags = [lambda { |req| __method__ }]
end
```